# Dynamically insert into table using sp_executesql in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I got error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
>   Invalid column name 'Front Brakes1'

when executing a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SqlStatement = 'INSERT INTO [SalesLT].[Product]('+ @Column+ ') VALUES('+@Value+')';
PRINT @SqlStatement
EXEC sys.sp_executesql  @SqlStatement, N'@Column NVARCHAR(MAX), @Value NVARCHAR(MAX)',@Column,@Value
```

`PRINT @SqlStatement` results in:

```
INSERT INTO [SalesLT].[Product](Name, ProductNumber, Color, StandardCost, ListPrice, Weight)  
VALUES ("Front Brakes1", "FB-98731", "Silver1", 47.286, 106.5, 317)
```

Additionally, here is the table design I wanna insert data into:

```
CREATE TABLE [SalesLT].[Product]
(
    [ProductID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [dbo].[Name] NOT NULL,
    [ProductNumber] [NVARCHAR](25) NOT NULL,
    [Color] [NVARCHAR](15) NULL,
    [StandardCost] [MONEY] NOT NULL,
    [ListPrice] [MONEY] NOT NULL,
    [Size] [NVARCHAR](5) NULL,
    [Weight] [DECIMAL](8, 2) NULL,
    [ProductCategoryID] [INT] NULL,
    [ProductModelID] [INT] NULL,
    [SellStartDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [SellEndDate] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [DiscontinuedDate] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [ThumbNailPhoto] [VARBINARY](MAX) NULL,
    [ThumbnailPhotoFileName] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [rowguid] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
)
```

Comment: How are you generating that statement, it looks very open to injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the T-SQL string literals in single quotes instead of double-quotes so that the resultant SQL statement is:

```
INSERT INTO [SalesLT].[Product](Name,ProductNumber,Color,StandardCost,ListPrice,Weight)
VALUES('Front Brakes1','FB-98731','Silver1',47.286,106.5,317);
```

Double-quotes (or square brackets) denote identifiers, such as table and column names.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, It work then i got a new bug :D

Comment: @LêBảoCường, not sure what your new bug is but I suggest you peruse [Why Parameters are a Best Practice](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/).